# Highlight text in primeng editor

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

I am using primeng editor to allow the user to write some python code in my app. I want to highlight the text where there's any syntax error. I've gone through the following link [syntax highlighting in quill.js](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/syntax/) but am unable to figure out how to use it.
How can I do this?

Currently I have this -

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="text" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>
```

Comment: Did you install it, already? Do you use ngx-quill or just quill?

Comment: I'm using quill & primeng editor module